# How to bind dynamic select options for each row in jsGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsgrid

i try to bind select option dynamically from database, 
for example:

```
$("#grid").jsGrid({
    editing: true,
    autoload: true,
    paging: false,
    pageLoading: true,
    data: result,
    fields: [
        { name: "Units", type: "select", title: "Units", items: ? },
    ]
});
```

but What's the data format to create select with options.
i try "itemTemplate" but didn't work well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build your `select` list before you instantiate the grid. Example:

```
const units = [ { id: 0, name: "cm"}, { id: 1, name: "inch" } ];
$("#grid").jsGrid({
// ...
fields: [
    { name: "Units", type: "select", title: "Units", 
      items: units, valueField: "id", textField: "name" },
 ]
});
```

Working demo at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OlGe/xpvt214o/856545/).

If you are talking about different rows having different drop down lists for the **same** column, then the built-in `select` type may not be useful. You have to render the `editTemplate` yourself. A simple working example is in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OlGe/oank52ye/3/).

Comment: Thank you for your attention..but "const units" make select options for all row. i want to bind select options completely dynamic for each row!!

Comment: I have updated the answer with another JSFiddle. You are aware that drop down list is meaningful only in edit mode?

Comment: Thank you for your attention again!!

Comment: but i want a dynamic  option. for example 1st row: options=[a,b,c] ,2st row: options= [d,e,f] ,etc. its my need and i guess js-grid can't do it...i wish u understand what do i want.

Comment: My updated fiddle does just that. First row is showing [mm, cm, meter], second row is showing [inch, foot, yard]. In what areas does it not meet what you want? Did you check it out?

Comment: it work. i didn't see new update. thank you so much.